# When is a Custom Label Managed?

Tags: customlabel

For our package we have loads of labels.
We maintain a general label file with labels and have translations in separate files.

What occured to us is that some labels are not assigned as "Managed - Released" in our packaging org. Meaning, in Setup>Custom Labels for some labels there is no "Managed - Released" icon. Some labels are already in our system for months.

How can you control what custom labels are and what labels are not managed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are managed if they are explicitly added to your managed package, and they are subsequently uploaded as part of a package version. Explicit inclusion is when the label is added to the package manually by using the Add Component button on the package or updating the package manifest in the metadata API.

Until there is an explicit link to the label, and they are uploaded, they are not part of the package. In other words, the labels you have that are not managed do no have any hard links in your package's metadata.

Dynamic access won't create a hard link, e.g. getting labels in Aura (e.g. `$A.get('$Label.'+labelName)`. In those cases, you need to include a hard link to the label elsewhere in your package to force the label to be included in the package.

Comment: This is, I believe, for 1GPs only. AFAIK there's no way to "explicitly" add a custom label to the (1GP) package. I.e. labels have to be referenced by other metadata (such as Apex classes) that are added to the package in order to be included. I believe for a 2GP all labels in the label file in the package directory should be part of the package (though haven't confirmed).

Comment: @sfdcfox, Thanks for your answer. Aaaah, so what you are saying is that, if you don't have a reference somewhere to the label it will not be part of the package. I checked all the labels that are not Managed-Released, and there seems a pattern that these labels are not referenced somewhere other than the label file itself.

We made functionality for it to be possible to reference the label in a field in a setting sobject. But because the label is 'not used' apperantly it will not be included in the package.

Comment: @sfdcfox, i looked into adding the custom label manually, but I can't seem to find the component type for adding custom labels. I navigated to the package, and clicked add on the Component tab. That page does not seem to have a component type for label or custom label...

Comment: @PhilW Looks like you're right. I could have sworn I remember adding labels to a package before, but now that I reflect on my past, I guess it's true that Salesforce just uses the hard links to determine inclusion. I'll amend this answer accordingly.

Comment: @PieterJacob I apparently misremembered. It's hard links only, as far as I can tell. If you're trying to use dynamic labels, they won't be packaged. One idea I found on this suggests creating a dummy page or component that uses hard links to the labels to force them to be included in the package.

Comment: We added various string constants, initialized from the labels we want to force to be included, in an Apex class. I think these can be private and otherwise unreferenced to still have the labels included.

Comment: @sfdcfox, thanks. This is exactly the idea we had.